# Convert date, turn NULLS blank and keep blanks?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, isnull

I have a column in a query that contains some blanks, NULLS and dates (as YYYYMMDD). I need to convert the dates to MM/DD/YYYY, remove the NULLs and keep the blanks blank.

When I try...

```
isnull(convert(char(10), cast(mytable as datetime), 101),  '')
```

the blanks turn to 01/01/1900, my NULLS become blank and my date converts. Any idea how to keep my blanks blank and not converting to 01/01/1900?

Comment: Do you store dates in a char/varchar column? Switch to a proper date data type, and coding will become much easier.

Comment: `case when rtrim(myCol) = '' then '' else convert(char(10), cast(myCol as datetime), 101) end` You made not need the `rtrim()`. You might also want to convert those empty strings to proper nulls. I presume this is SQL Server btw.

Comment: What does "remove the nulls" mean exactly?

Comment: I'd say the opposite, keep NULLs, don't even allow blanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is confusing to call a column "mytable", so I will call it "DateText" in this answer.

To prevent converting the empty string to `'1900-01-01`', you can  use the `isnull()` function to temporarily map the empty value to null - `isnull(DateText, '')`. You already have logic that will map the null value back to an empty string after the conversion.

The updated expression would then be:

```
isnull(convert(char(10), cast(nullif(DateText, '') as datetime), 101),  '')
```

Results:

| DateText | Original | Fixed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20240111 | 01/11/2024 | 01/11/2024 |
|  | 01/01/1900 |  |
| *null* |  |  |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/stpdjhSG).

Answer (score 0):

This is using T-SQL (MS SQL Server)

```
 select case when IsNull(mydatecolumn, '') = '' then '' 
             else convert(varchar(10), mydatecolumn, 101)
        end as newdatecolumn
```